Electron + Expressjs. works in development. but with build api gets stuck at pending state
I'm using the electron with express framework to run a desktop application. application is working perfectly in development mode.
If I released an application with an electron builder, it's not starting the express nodejs server.
index.js(server file)
const express = require("express");
const excelRoute = require("./route/excelRoute.js");
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use("/", excelRoute);

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});

main.js
const electron = require('electron');
const browserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const app = electron.app;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
require('./index.js')

app.on('ready', function () {
  var appWindow;

  //appWindow
  appWindow = new browserWindow({
    width: 1120,
    height: 620,
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true
    },
    // icon: __dirname + '/public/icon/icon.png' 
  });
  appWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/public/index.html`),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true
  }));

  //appWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
});

// close app after all windows are closed
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
})

package.json
{
  "name": "excelapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Your app description",
  "author": "Your Name",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch . --exec electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.yourcompany.yourapp",
    "mac": {
      "category": "your.app.category.type"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.4.0",
    "express": "^4.21.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^33.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.13",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13"
  }
}

i have tried different packagers, but still all works fine in dev not after building it.

might be due to port conflict, meaning you are running the development version and trying to run the production version at the same time on same port. I have made an app with electron and express like a week ago and I didnt make separate files for them and I used electron-forge to make .exe file. Currently, its working completely fine. Can you check your port 3000 and see if it's empty or running with netstat -a -n -o | find "3000"?
